# Computing annual spatial (zonal) statistics of a NetCDF file for polygons in shape-file

Tags: python, shapefile, polygon, spatial-statistics, netcdf

I have a NetCDF-file containing annual GDP data for Africa. I also have a shape-file containing provinces in Africa as polygons.

I now want to compute statistics (ie. mean, sum, ...) per polygon based on the data of the nc-file in this polygon using `python`.

Have tried various approaches with `xarray`, `rioaxarray`, `rasterio`, etc., but none of them worked.

Has anyone a code snippet/approach how to code that correctly?

Comment: Add your code attempt or your question will be closed. I would use [rasterstats](https://pythonhosted.org/rasterstats/). You have multiple rasters, one for each year? Or one raster with each year as a band?

Comment: Thanks for hinting me to rasterstats - did not know it yet and it solved my problem. I did not add my code attempts in the question to not "steer" people in certain directions.

Answer (score 6):

I used this code to get want I wanted:

```
# import packages
import xarray as xr
import rasterio as rio
import geopandas as gpd
import rasterstats as rstats

# load and read shp-file with geopandas
shp_fo = r'../path/to/shp_file.shp'
shp_df = gpd.read_file(shp_fo)

# load and read netCDF-file to dataset and get datarray for variable
nc_fo = r'../path/to/netCDF_file.nc'
nc_ds = xr.open_dataset(nc_fo)
nc_var = nc_ds['var_name']

# get all years for which we have data in nc-file
years = nc_ds['time'].values

# get affine of nc-file with rasterio
affine = rio.open(nc_fo).transform

# go through all years
for year in years:
    # get values of variable pear year
    nc_arr = nc_var.sel(time=year)
    nc_arr_vals = nc_arr.values
    # go through all geometries and compute zonal statistics
    for i in range(len(shp_df)):
        print(rstats.zonal_stats(shp_df.geometry, nc_arr_vals, affine=affine, stats="mean min max"))
        print('')
```

Comment: Could this data also be exported to csv?

Comment: what exactly from this code? the resulting statistics come as a dictionary, that can be written to csv-file.